# Twitter Sentiment Analysis in Python, Lemmatization in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, analysis, lemmatization

I am trying to produce a very simple twitter sentiment analysis. I have so far been able to pre-process my tweets however I am greatly struggling to lemmatize within my data frame. This is my code so far:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords  # Importing Natural Language Toolkit
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/sarfrazkhan/Desktop/amazon.csv')  # Loading Amazon data set into code
df = df['x'].str.replace('http\S+|www.\S+', '', case=False)  # Removing URL's from data set
df = df.str.replace(r'\<.*\>', '')  # Removing noise contained in '< >' these parenthesis
df = df.str.replace('RT ', '', case=False)  # Removing the phrase 'RT" from all strings
df = df.str.replace('@[^\s]+', '', case=False)  # Removing '@' and the following twitter handle from strings
df = df.str.replace('[^\w\s]', ' ')  # Removing any punctuation
df = df.str.replace('\r\n', ' ')  # Removing '\r\n' which is present in some strings
df = df.str.replace('\d+', '').str.lower().str.strip()  # Removing numbers, capitalisation and white space
df = df.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)  # Tokenizing data set

stop = nltk.download('stopwords')  # Downloading stop words
stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))  # Selecting English stop words
df = df.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop])  # Removing stop words from each string

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemma_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos='a') for w in df]
```

I am struggling to get my Lemmatizer to work and constantly met with errors possibly due to the fact my dataset is in a list form. (which I am struggling to work around) The Excel which I am trying to process is simply a long list of tweets with the heading 'x'. You can see on line 6 of my code that I focus primarily on this column, however I'm unsure if this is the correct way to do it!

My expected outcome would be a list of words which have been lemmatised correctly within their respective rows, to which I can then carry out a sentiment analysis.

These are the first few lines of my data frame before attempting the lemmatising process:

```
1      [swinging, pendulum, wall, clock, love, give, ...
2                                 [enter, via, gleam, l]
3      [screw, every, follow, gets, nude, dms, dm, pr...
4      [bishop, law, coming, soon, bishop, series, bo...
5      [adventures, bella, amp, emily, book, series, ...
6      [written, books, various, genres, amazon, kind...
7      [author, books, amwriting, fantasy, mystery, p...
8      [wonderful, mentor, recent, times, graham, kee...
9      [available, amazon, ebay, disabilities, hidden...
10     [screw, every, follow, gets, nude, dms, dm, pr...
```

Comment: Can you post the errors and also a sample of `df` just before you call the lemmatizer?

Comment: 0      [top, stock, choices, microsoft, amazon, apple...
1      [swinging, pendulum, wall, clock, love, give, ...

These are the first two lines of the output (can't add anymore but goes up to 999 entries)

(TypeError: unhashable type: 'list') is the error code I seem to keep getting and can't work around it

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to lemmatize an actual list hence the error.

`... for w in df` -> here, `w` is the list, rather than each element of each list.

To get around this you could use pandas apply to pass each row to a function (assuming df is a `pd.DataFrame` and not a `pd.Series`. If it's a Series and the below doesn't work, try `df = df.to_frame()` first) :

```
def df_lemmatize(row):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    row.at['lemma_words'] = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w, pos='a') for w in row.x]
    return row
    
df = df.apply(df_lemmatize, axis=1)
```

`df_lemmatize` will iterate over each element in the list, lemmatize it and then add the new list to a new column `lemma_words`.

Comment: I get the error TypeError: df_lemmatize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: Ah that means you're passing it a series. Can you try doing `df = df.to_frame()` first to convert to a DataFrame instead of a Series?